# CCA Emulate Android error

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova, windows-10

I'm making an android app in the Chrome API. I got my emulator set up and everything seems to be working fine except CCA throws a weird error.

```
C:\Users\Giovanni\Google Drive\cde\dwm\DerpyWorld>cca emulate android
    cca v0.5.0
    Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Giovanni\Google  Drive\cde\dwm\DerpyWorld\hooks\before_prep are\cca-check.js" "C:\Users\Giovanni\Google Drive\cde\dwm\DerpyWorld"
    Running command: cmd "/s /c ""C:\Users\Giovanni\Google Drive\cde\dwm\DerpyWorld\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat" --emulator""
'C:\Users\Giovanni\Google' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Giovanni\Google Drive\cde\dwm\DerpyWorld\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
    throw e;
           ^                 
    Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,C:\Users\Giovanni\Google Drive\cde\dwm\DerpyWorld\platforms\android\gradl
    ew,assembleX86Debug,-b,C:\Users\Giovanni\Google Drive\cde\dwm\DerpyWorld\platforms\android\build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.dae
    mon=true,-x,lint,-x,lintVitalX86Release,-x,lintVitalArmv7Release,-x,compileLint,-x,copyReleaseLint,-x,copyDebugLint
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
        at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Giovanni\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cca\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\c
    ordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)

C:\Users\Giovanni\Google Drive\cde\dwm\DerpyWorld>
```

Any ideas?

---

Oke, well I fixed the last issue by moving it into a folder with no spaces... a really bad fix imo. Of course, issues continue.

C:\Users\Giovanni\android\DerpyWorld>cca emulate android
cca v0.5.0
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\Giovanni\android\DerpyWorld\hooks\before_prepare\cca-check.js C:\Users\Giovanni\android\DerpyWorld
Running command: C:\Users\Giovanni\android\DerpyWorld\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat --emulator

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Giovanni\android\DerpyWorld\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 27
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'android']
  >   Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.2.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\Giovanni\android\DerpyWorld\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-1.10-all.zip
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.178 secs

C:\Users\Giovanni\android\DerpyWorld\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,C:\Users\Giovanni\android\DerpyWorld\platforms\android\gradlew,assembleX86Debug,-b,C:\Users\Giovanni\android\DerpyWorld\platforms\android\build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-x,lint,-x,lintVitalX86Release,-x,lintVitalArmv7
Release,-x,compileLint,-x,copyReleaseLint,-x,copyDebugLint
Error: C:\Users\Giovanni\android\DerpyWorld\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Giovanni\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cca\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)

C:\Users\Giovanni\android\DerpyWorld>C:\Users\Giovanni\android\DerpyWorld\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-1.10-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

`cmd "/s /c ""C:\Users\Giovanni\Google Drive\cde\dwm\DerpyWorld\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat" --emulator""`

The path is not passed properly as a parameter, and the parse is not reading past the  in the path.

There is a setting somewhere in CCA that determines the value of this line, and it is incorrect. You need to double-check your ""s in that string, as they are causing your error.

Comment: How would I change that line if the program generates it?